# Is there an open source iOS app that allows user to sign up and log in with Facebook authorizations?

Tags: ios

I am interested in learning the best practices on managing user session and organizing the ViewControllers for signup/login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Facebook [HackBook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook) Sample iOS app, that should help along with the official [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

> #### Hackbook for iOS
>
> Demonstrates how to use the Facebook Platform to integrate your iOS
>   app. This sample initially asks the user to log in to Facebook then
>   provides the user with a sample set of Facebook API calls such as
>   logging out, uninstalling the app, publishing news feeds, making app
>   requests, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is here that you should know,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

- Step 3
- Step 4

is the most relevant to your question